# macro with variable being active cell and linking the macro to a hyperlink

Tags: vba, excel

So what I have are two lists of information about people, one list is details of these people and the other is their schedule. Therefore, what I am trying to do is on the schedule I want to be able to click the name of the person and have a message box pop up and display all of their details.

So far my code works. I just don't know how to implement the active cell as a variable when referencing the details.

I don't know how to make this code dynamic so that when I click a different link it provides details based on who or where I clicked.

```
Private Sub 
Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal target As Hyperlink)
Run ("details")

End Sub

Sub details()
Dim msg As String, i As Long, a As Variant
msg = ""
i = 2
    For Each a In Array("B", "D")
        msg = msg & Cells(i, a).Value & vbTab
    Next a
MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

The image shows what happens when I click "john"
and what I want is to put the hyperlinked "john on a different page and for that hyperlink to be dynamic.

[image]

Comment: Why do you have `For i = 2 to 2`? Just make `i = 2` and save yourself that loop. Can you give an example on how you want this to work?

Comment: so on sheet one I have a list of people in column 1 and column 3:5 have their details. On sheet 2 I have the same list of people but the other columns are a schedule. what I want is to hyperlink the list of people on sheet 2 and when I click the hyperlink it brings a message box displaying the information from sheet one column 3:5 from whichever person I clicked on. The purpose of this is to reference a persons credentials while looking at the schedule.

Comment: I added an image to try and reference a little more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have a code that (*I am hoping to work and*) should be placed in the worksheet where the schedules are.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

' Declare and set the variable to check if the event(dblclick)
' happened in the desired range - A.
Dim rIntersect As Range
Set rIntersect = Intersect(Target, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetOfSchedule").Range("A:A"))
' Exits this sub if there is no change in the desired range.
If rIntersect Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'cancel the doubleclick action.
Cancel = True

' Declare and set the variable that refers to their
' detials in the 'SheetOfDetails'.
Dim rEmployee As Range
Set rEmployee = LookFor(rIntersect.Value, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetOfDetails"), 1)

' Declare the use the variable for looping
Dim iLoop As Integer
Dim strHolder As String     '<~ string that will hold the details
For iLoop = 1 To 3          '<~ change this to your requirements
  strHolder = strHolder & rEmployee.Offset(0, iLoop - 1).Value & vbTab
Next

MsgBox strHolder
End Sub

Private Function LookFor(NameOfEmployee As String, inSheet As Worksheet, inColumn As Integer) As Range
' This function will look for your employee name
' and return a range object where you can get
' details adjacent to this cell.
Dim lLoop As Long

With inSheet                                                '<~ make sure that we are working with the correct sheet
  For lLoop = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row     '<~ loops through the last row
    If .Cells(lLoop, inColumn).Value = NameOfEmployee Then  '<~ loop until you find the emp name
      Set LookFor = .Cells(lLoop, inColumn)                 '<~ set the function to return that cell
      Exit Function                                         '<~ exit to save from
    End If                                                  '   unnecesary loopings.
  Next
End With

End Function
```

Comment: YES! Great thank you so much works like a charm on the first try!